# How to get the actual Xpath/ locator expression in selenium/ java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to obtain xpath expression. The locators are already declared using the @FindBy but this is required to get during the test case execution regardless any locator is utilized here.

Below expression like is required to be stored in a database once the element is located so that it matches with an entry (in db table) when new test execution is done. (required)

```
//*[@role='img' and contains(text(),'search')]
```

below is the code:

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@role='img' and contains(text(),'search')]") public WebElement searchPopup;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@data-test='userMenu']") public WebElement userMenu;

    public waitForElementVisible {
        waitForLocatorVisibility(searchPopup);
        System.out.println(searchPopup);
    }

    public static WebElement waitForLocatorVisibility(WebElement element) {
        // standard webDriverWait method from selenium
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(45, 1)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }
```

If I print the returned element or print it directly, it shows something like this in the console:

> element is :[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS
> (1679120c-e1f7-4422-8222-93f31208f037)] -> xpath: //*[@role='img' and
> contains(text(),'search')]]

Whereas the unique key change when tests are executed on different browser like Chrome. And it shows Chrome instead of firefox in logs.

Is there any way to get/ print the actual XPath expression here like:

```
//*[@role='img' and contains(text(),'search')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to extract the locator from WebElement.
Since you are using PageFactory you need to make the sure the element is found on DOM before you call this method because PageFactory wll intialize these fields with a proxy and they don't contain your webelement until it is found in DOM , the find will happen once you do some kind of action like click or gettext

```
private String getLocatorFromElement(WebElement element) {
      By by = null;
      String[] pathVariables = (element.toString().split("->")[1].replaceFirst("(?s)(.*)\\]",
          "$1" + "")).split(":");
      String selector = pathVariables[0].trim();
      String value = pathVariables[1].trim();
      switch (selector) {
         case "id":
            by = By.id(value);
            break;
         case "className":
            by = By.className(value);
            break;
         case "tagName":
            by = By.tagName(value);
            break;
         case "xpath":
            by = By.xpath(value);
            break;
         case "cssSelector":
            by = By.cssSelector(value);
            break;
         case "linkText":
            by = By.linkText(value);
            break;
         case "name":
            by = By.name(value);
            break;
         case "partialLinkText":
            by = By.partialLinkText(value);
            break;
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("locator : " + selector + " not found!!!");
      }
      return by.toString().split(":")[1];
   }
```

Like in below example i am doing gettext before retrieving the locator value from Webelement

```
PageFactory.initElements(drover, obj);
      drover.get("https://www.google.com/");
      obj.userMenu.getText();
      String by = obj.getLocatorFromElement(obj.userMenu);
      System.out.println(by);
```